# how to reuse jQuery code in different selectors？

Tags: jquery

I write code like this below,the differences between is selectors,so how to reuse the similar method in less code? how about using a factory function?

```
$(".tc_banzhu").click(function() {
  $(".banzhuDon").fadeIn(200);
  //get the width and height of the dialog
  var tc_hgt = $(".banzhuDon .popup_box").height() / 2;
  var tc_wid = $(".banzhuDon .popup_box").width() / 2;
  $(".banzhuDon.popup_box").css({
    marginLeft: tc_wid * -1 + "px",
    marginTop: tc_hgt * -1 + "px"
  });
});
$(".tc_ban").click(function() {
  $(".banDon").fadeIn(200);
  var tc_hgt = $(".banDon .popup_box").height() / 2;
  var tc_wid = $(".banDon .popup_box").width() / 2;
  $(".banDon.popup_box").css({
    marginLeft: tc_wid * -1 + "px",
    marginTop: tc_hgt * -1 + "px"
  });
});
$(".tc_banner").click(function() {
  $(".bannerDon").fadeIn(200);
  var tc_hgt = $(".bannerDon .popup_box").height() / 2;
  var tc_wid = $(".bannerDon .popup_box").width() / 2;
  $(".bannerDon.popup_box").css({
    marginLeft: tc_wid * -1 + "px",
    marginTop: tc_hgt * -1 + "px"
  });
});
```

Comment: Please let me know if my answer is not working. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36036587/4763793

Comment: I put code on https://jsbin.com/pebuma/edit?html,css,js,console,output
In fact,I do not set the dialog height value, marginTop: tc_hgt * -1 + "px" do not work,anyway,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function expression for the click callback function:

```
var action = function(e) {
    $(e).fadeIn(200);
    var tc_hgt = $(e).find(".popup_box").height() / 2;
    var tc_wid = $(e).find(".popup_box").width() / 2;
    if ($(e).hasClass(".popup_box")) $(e).css({marginLeft: tc_wid * -1 + "px", marginTop: tc_hgt * -1 + "px"});
};    

$(".tc_banzhu, .tc_ban, .tc_banner").click(function() {
    action(this);
});
```

Comment: “.pop_box" is not the children of ".tc_banzhu, .tc_ban, .tc_banner",I write like this  <div class="popup_bg banzhuDon none"></div> and set them at the end of HTML page,when I click a button,the dialog which matches display.

Comment: Implemented hasClass to check whether the element has a ".pop_box" class.